# How does Spring framework autowire a collection

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I've never seen an autowired collection:

```
@Service
public class SomeFactory {
    @Autowired
    private List<Foo> foos;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        for(Foo foo: foos) { 
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

In init() method, I can see foos has several entries already. I guess Spring knows who's supposed to be the entry of foos. But, how? What should I do if I want to add a Foo object into foos? Need to configure in a property file, or any other idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Spring's BeanFactory is basically a registry of beans. These beans can be declared using XML, or using `@Bean`-annotated methods in a Configuration class, or be automatically discovered using package scanning.

When you ask for a `List<Foo>`, Spring finds all the beans that are of type Foo, creates a List containing those beans, and injects that list.

The [documentation about Autowired](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation) explains it, BTW:

> It is also possible to provide all beans of a particular type from the ApplicationContext by adding the annotation to a field or method that expects an array of that type

Answer (score 1):

> **In init() method, I can see foos has several entries already. I guess Spring knows who's supposed to be the entry of foos. But, how?**

When the Application Context / Bean Factory is created, **by default (if not specify otherwise with lazy init or non singleton scope)**, all the beans are also created. **The app context knows about these beans**. So when we try to `@Autowire` collections of a particular type beans like  `private List<Foo> foos;`, Spring find all foos, add them to list and inject into the dependent bean.

> **What should I do if I want to add a Foo object into foos? Need to configure in a property file, or any other idea?**

There are multiple ways to do it. Can choose one suitable option, based on requirement.

- Declare the beans in an bean **configuration `XML` file**. Flexible. But you may not like doing it in XML.
- **`@Component` annotation on a bean class**. The class will be scanned by Spring with Component Scan configured. No XML but less flexible. Bean class definition and declaration are tightly coupled. Can not create the  `@Component` bean in a  different `Application Context`.
- **`@Bean` annotation on a method** that returns the bean inside an **`@Configuration` annotated class**. Preferable. Bean class definition and declaration are decoupled and done though annotation only. We can create the `@Bean` annotated bean from the method in a different `Application Context` as well.